# iOS Check wifi and Bluetooth working

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, wifi, core-bluetooth

My Intention is straight forward. I want to check whether wifi and Bluetooth of a device is working or not. I know few approach that I got from stackoverflow and apple developer resource. But all possible solution doesn't work for me as the application where it will test will not have any wifi network and other bluetooth device around.
I have got an idea to test this without any dependencey -

wifi - 
I can able to read Mac address and Wifi router address for device.Depending on this, can I say Wifi is working for this device.

Bluetooth - 
Any idea, what will be the response for following code for a device  which has bluetooth but not working/defected.

```
CBCentralManagerState == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported
```

please note: to check this, I will not have other wifi network or bluetooth. When application will run, assume device buletooth and wifi is open.

any suggestion appriciable. Thanks

Comment: If bluetooth is turned off then you will never enter the PoweredOn CBcentral state

Comment: Although not specifically for wifi the reachability library is great for checking if there is an internet connection

Comment: As I mention, there is no wifi arround it, so implement reachability will always reply NO. Thats way I can identify whether wifi is working or not.thanks for your suggestion @angry